# How to ask for a compound word in a data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

I want to get all the positions in this dataframe in which the OFFICE_LOCATION is in CALIFORNIA. It doesn't matter if is in southern or north.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `OFFICE_LOCATION` column to a string and search for the substring `CALIFORNIA`.

```
df[df['OFFICE_LOCATION'].str.contains('CALIFORNIA')]
```